# Using regex variable as normal variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
x.innerHTML.replace(/@(.*?)/g, '<img src="'+get_data($1)+'">$1</img>')
```

Is there any way to use $1 for the get_data function? Thank for your advices.

#### Update

It was made clear in the comments that the OP also wanted to match data in the form @word and pull out the word string specifically.

Comment: What is $1 here? Are you asking if you can use the regex from the first argument as the argument to the function `get_data`?

Comment: @fuzic $1 is the contents of the inner parentheses in the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `x.innerHTML.replace(rx,function)` and the function will be called with these arguments:

- The matched substring
- $1,$2...
- The offset of the match
- The full match

So you can just do this:

```
x.innerHTML.replace(/@(\S+)/g,function(string,data1){

 return '<img src="'+get_data(data1)+'">'+data1+'</img>');

});
```

Here's the [MDN Docs on replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Damn. I even saw the quote from a book I guess I didn't read 100% of with that replace func arg and somehow I never found out about that. *starts running .length on every native method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/creepyzero/4MnJG/ It seems like data = nothing...It's just an example.

Comment: (.*?) I hadn't noticed, but this makes no sense.  To match all the text just use the *, to match the first character use ?.  To match the first word use (.*)/w

Comment: I don't understand sorry. I just started to learn regex a few days ago.

Comment: No problem.  What do you actually want to match?  This matches everything: http://jsfiddle.net/4MnJG/1/

Comment: I want to get "Test" and "Test2" out, and put them in form of variables so I can you them for the get_data function.

Comment: This matches what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/4MnJG/3/  It looks for things in the form @lettersornumbers and pulls out the text.  I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you for your fast responses and efforts !

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
var str = x.innerHTML.replace(/@(.*?)/g, "$1");
var img = '<img src="'+get_data(str)+'">'+str+'</img>';
```

Comment: No it would not work, because it doesn't actually replace the innerHTML value on the element with the string.  It replaces the innerHTML with the contents of the regex group, and then creates an img string which contains the correct string.